# How to remove item from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> one by one in android

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am new to Android. I am Using "com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView" to show my items(playing cards). In the List I am getting 8 cards in the first attempt. What I want if I again call the method the there must be 7 cards so on means 1 cards must be remove from the list at each time till the list gets empty. But I am not able not do this removing of item from the list. I am posting my code here. Help will be appreciated.

MainActivity.java

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aList9;
Button btn_aditional_card;
HorizontalListView list1;

int[] cards3 = new int[]{
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1,
        R.drawable.card1

};


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_aditional_card = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_aditional_card);
    list1 = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

btn_aditional_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          add8();
        }
    });
  }

 public void add8() {

   final android.view.animation.Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
    list1.startAnimation(animScale);

    aList9 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("card", Integer.toString(cards3[i]));
        aList9.add(hm);
    }

    String[] from = {"card"};
    int[] to = {R.id.ImageView};

    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList9, R.layout.activity_animation__adapter, from, to);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               aList9.remove(aList9.size() - 1);
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
        });
     }
```

Here removing of item from the list must be done on list1.setOnItemClickListener but I don't have any idea how.

Comment: Call `aList9.remove(position)` to remove clicked item

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it will remove which position of the list

Comment: then what is your requirement ?

Comment: I justwant  to remove the card from the list each time when i click the button btn_aditional_card....that's it

Comment: Which card you need to remove?

Comment: If just remove the last card from list then `list.remove(list.size() - 1);`

Comment: aList9.remove(position) not working in on list.onitemclick....still I am getting 8 cards on button click again and again..

Comment: @AndroidLover In `btn_aditional_card.setOnItemClickListener` you are initializing the entire stuff again and again. So when you click the button, `add8( )` is executed and in that you are populating 8 views again.

Comment: @ghostman your method is also not working still getting 8 cards again and again....

Comment: It cannot be, post your code.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet Yes you are right....but how can I remove the item one by one on list.setOnItemClickListener....

Comment: @AndroidLover Posting an answer.

Comment: @ghostman Check my edited code....I put it according to you and Run on my device but nothing hapenning

Comment: At first, it's bad reinitialize adapter and reset it into list. Just initialize it at once time and get it list.getAdapter() (I don't remember), then add or remove value from it. After call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: And you need remove `aList9.remove(position);`, and not need to reset listener every time.

Comment: you need to remove them one by one after only one click ?!!

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat Yes one item on one click....means if i click the button first time the list must have 8 cards and again if i click the button then it should have 7 cards and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last item from the list like;

```
if (aList9.size() > 0) {
   aList9.remove(aList9.size() - 1);
}
```

Another solution,
Take Length of your integer array and traverse the loop inside your add8 method according to this length and at the end of the method decrement the length by one, like;

```
int length = cards3.length;
```

Inside your add8 method;

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hm.put("card", Integer.toString(cards3[i]));
    aList9.add(hm);
}
```

After for loop decrement the length like;

```
length--;
```

Hope you'll get the solution.

Comment: you have to define the length variable as a class variable not inside the method

Answer (score 0):

In your list1.setOnItemClickListener, do this:

```
if (aList9.size() > 0) {
   aList9.remove(aList9.size() - 1);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When removing item from data list, you have to **notify your adapter** to update view.

Comment: I notify my adapter to notifyDataSetChanged(); still not working your code.

Comment: @AndroidLover reinit your adapter with your new arraylist and then, set adapter to listview again, i guaranty that this will work 100%! for this thing, you have to make your adapter variable global at your class, put it outside of any method!

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity the code should look like.I am using arraylist instead you can use hashmap.This code is only to show you way what you need to do. follow this code in your project you will get solution this is tested in my site and working fine  you need to change somewhere according to your code.In button click i am only removing last item from arraylist and notifying that dataset changed.hope it will help you.

```
ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrlist.add("B");
        arrlist.add("C");
        arrlist.add("D");
        arrlist.add("E");
        arrlist.add("F");
        arrlist.add("G");
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        Button btnShowList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowList);


        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrlist);
        //Listview adapter
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);




        btnShowList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (arrlist.size() > 0) {
                    arrlist.remove(arrlist.size() - 1);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: @AndroidLover you need to move your code of populating list to the outside of button click

Comment: @AndroidLover did you trie it? please let me know

Comment: @AndroidLover what is output??

Comment: I have to put these cards in int [ ]  because i am using these at many places and times some time 13 all cards here i am using only eight according to you if i use this code then i have to declare more then 5 times Arraylist for these cards..

Comment: @AndroidLover first remove your code of population listview from function and place it in onCreate method

Comment: @AndroidLover then add the code on button click which i have added

Comment: @AndroidLover then check for output and tell me

Comment: I tried your code and it not working for me.....First I am showing near by 100 cards in the listview in parts means some time 10,14,13 etc.. and after that i have to show these 8 cards...and when i apply your code in my activity my app is not responding as it like too.....everything is getting hospos...

Comment: @AndroidLover you need to apply some logic so that listview should be populated only once

Comment: @AndroidLover are you succeed or not if you need any help then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//make your Adapter global
private SimpleAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aList9;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    add8();

    btn_aditional_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // on button click you can add a view to the listview if you want
            // if you don't want this just comment out the following line
            // i still don't understand what you want to do with this button
            alist9.add(...);
            // if you add stuff in the array list then notify the adapter
            // it will update the view
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}

public void add8() {
    // initialize your ArrayList and listview
    //populate them
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        // do your stuff.
        // populate the list
    }

    // initialize your adapter as before
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(....);
    listview.setadapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // delete the items like this
            // check if size is greater than 0 and then remove
           aList9.remove(aList9.size() - 1);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
    });


}

}
```

Comment: btn_aditional_card....will load the list with items till the list gets empty....let me try your code...